# Solvability of this General Pell's Equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

If $p\equiv -1 \pmod{12}$ is a prime, does this general Pell's equation always have integer solutions for $x$ and $y$?
$$x^2-3y^2=-p$$
I have tested that this is true for all values of $p$ up to $8\cdot 10^7$ but I failed to give a proof for it. It appears that there exists a solution with $x^2\le 2p$. It doesn't work for non-prime $p$, or simply $p \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ or $p \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check only the primes or also the composites of this form ?

Comment: Only primes. Composites don't work, for example p=35. Edited the question.

Comment: What about $2^2-3\cdot 7^2=-143$ ?

Comment: Oh I meant composite $p$ does not always have a solution but some do. Perhaps it is because $11|p$ but $p=935$ does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Dedekind's second proof for Fermat's sum of two squares theorem,
we first note that $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ as by the law of quadratic reciprocity,
$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)={\left(-1\right)}^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{3-1}{2}}=-1.$$
Therefore, there exists an integer $m$ such that $m^2-3\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.
Now consider the quadratic order $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, an unique factorization domain. Note that $p$ is not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ since
$p \mid m^2-3$ but $p \nmid m-\sqrt{3}$ and $p \nmid m-\sqrt{3}$.
Hence, we can write $p=uv$ where $u=x_1+y_1\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ and
$v=x_2+y_2\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ are not units (elements with norm 1).
Note that $$p^2=N(p)=N(u)\cdot N(v)=(x^2_1-3y^2_1)(x^2_2-3y^2_2)$$
as the norm $N(\cdot)$ is a completely multiplicative function.
Since neither of $u$ and $v$ is a unit, we have $N(u)=N(v)=-p$ (as $N(u)\equiv N(v)\equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod{3}$ but $p\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ so $N(u),N(v)\neq p$) and thus
$$-p=x^2_1-3y^2_1=x^2_2-3y^2_2$$ for some integers $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$.
So the equation indeed has a solution for all $p\equiv 11 \pmod{12}$

Comment: Nice! There seem to exist infinitely many $d$ such that the maximal order of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is a PID.  Wonder if there are many primes among them, and if you could extend your argument in that case.